# Making a picture box become visible / invisible on a certain integer? (C#)

Tags: c#, image, visible, invisible

I was wondering how I would make a picture box become invisible or visible when a certain integer matches.

My program revolves around 2 players going around a board, and when they add there 2 Di up, they will move the amount of spaces.

My problem being, My friend and I have no idea what is wrong with the current code we have, it throws no errors which baffles him, especially myself.

I've made it so my program add's the Di up on every roll, and add's it to the integer.

Anyone have any idea's on whats wrong? If not, a better approach?

**Code**

```
private void SelectPos(PictureBox pic)
{
    PictureBox[] numbers = { P1_1, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P1_10, P1_11, P1_12, P1_13, P1_14, P1_15, P1_16, P1_17, P1_18, P1_19, P1_20, P1_21, P1_22, P1_23, P1_24, P1_25, P1_26, P1_27, P1_28, P1_29, P1_30, P1_31, P1_32, P1_33, P1_34, P1_35, P1_36, P1_37, P1_38, P1_39, P1_40, P1_41, P1_42, P1_43, P1_44, P1_45, P1_46, P1_47, P1_48, P1_49 };
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pic == numbers[i])
        {
            numbers[i].Visible = true;
            MessageBox.Show("k");
        }

        {
            numbers[i].Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show("l");
        }
    }
}

private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roll();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    Roll2();
    Goes_Num.Text = (int.Parse(Goes_Num.Text) + 1).ToString();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Goes_Num.Text) % 2 == 0)
    {
        WhichPlayer.Text = "Player 2";
        P2_Number.Text = (int.Parse(P2_Number.Text) + 1).ToString();
        int p2Int = Convert.ToInt32(P2_Pos.Text);
        P2_Pos.Text = (p2Int + dice + dice2).ToString();
    }
    else if (Convert.ToInt32(Goes_Num.Text) % 2 != 0)
    {
        WhichPlayer.Text = "Player 1";
        P1_Number.Text = (int.Parse(P1_Number.Text) + 1).ToString();
        int p1Int = Convert.ToInt32(P1_Pos.Text);
        P1_Pos.Text = (p1Int + dice + dice2).ToString();
        int P1 = (Convert.ToInt32(P1_Pos.Text));
        SelectPos(P1_1);

        /*switch (P1)
        {
            case 1:
                P1_1.Visible = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                P1_2.Visible = true;
                break;
        }*/

        /*String[] hi = { "1", "2" };
        for (int i = 0; i < hi.Length; i++)
        {
            var visible = p1
            if(visible == hi[i])
            {
                hi[i].Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                hi[i].Visible = false;
            }

        }*/
    }
}
```

(P1-1 all the way to P1-49 are images)

Thanks,
James

Comment: it's always better to add the code to your question than the picture of it.also I think you missing "else" in your for loop

Comment: You need to provide us with more information for us to help you better. What is the error that comes up? Where does the error happen?

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code, and where would the else be?

Comment: It simply makes the message box show "l" 49 times and the other one once

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to pass an `int` to your `SelectPos` function but it expects a `PictureBox`. You could fix this doing something similar to the following:

```
private void SelectPos(int pic)
{
    PictureBox[] numbers = { P1_1, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P1_10, P1_11, P1_12, P1_13, P1_14, P1_15, P1_16, P1_17, P1_18, P1_19, P1_20, P1_21, P1_22, P1_23, P1_24, P1_25, P1_26, P1_27, P1_28, P1_29, P1_30, P1_31, P1_32, P1_33, P1_34, P1_35, P1_36, P1_37, P1_38, P1_39, P1_40, P1_41, P1_42, P1_43, P1_44, P1_45, P1_46, P1_47, P1_48, P1_49 };

    //Set all picture boxes to be not visible
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i].Visible = false;
    }

    //Set the picture at the given index to visible
    numbers[pic].Visible = true;
}

private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roll();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    Roll2();
    Goes_Num.Text = (int.Parse(Goes_Num.Text) + 1).ToString();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Goes_Num.Text) % 2 == 0)
    {
        WhichPlayer.Text = "Player 2";
        P2_Number.Text = (int.Parse(P2_Number.Text) + 1).ToString();
        int p2Int = Convert.ToInt32(P2_Pos.Text);
        P2_Pos.Text = (p2Int + dice + dice2).ToString();
    }
    else if (Convert.ToInt32(Goes_Num.Text) % 2 != 0)
    {
        WhichPlayer.Text = "Player 1";
        P1_Number.Text = (int.Parse(P1_Number.Text) + 1).ToString();
        int p1Int = Convert.ToInt32(P1_Pos.Text);
        P1_Pos.Text = (p1Int + dice + dice2).ToString();
        int P1 = (Convert.ToInt32(P1_Pos.Text));
        SelectPos(P1);
    }
}
```

You may have to manipulate the value of `pic` so that it is within the bounds of the array (0-48). For example if `pic` is between 1 and 49 you would need to subtract 1: `numbers[pic-1]`. Without seeing your whole program I can't tell you exactly how that part of the code would look but it should be pretty easy to figure out. If you aren't familiar with arrays and indexing check out [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm) link or just Google C# Arrays.

As a side note it would be better to the `numbers` array as a private member of the class this code is in. Unless the values in the array change there's no point in building the array every time the method is called.

Comment: We couldn't get your code working, we even messed around with it, with inspiration from you and came up with this: https://paste.jamdoog.com/raw/icopeyay

Comment: Entire code: https://paste.jamdoog.com/raw/epatuhil , Pictures: https://i.jamdoog.com/4E5U0H.png. The images are the  P1_x and P2_x.https://i.jamdoog.com/0l373M.png

Comment: There was a mistake in the original version of the code I posted. It should be `SelectPos(P1);`, assuming `P1` is the position of the image you want selected. Again, without the error messages and location the error occurs it's not that easy for us to help you.

Comment: Just some quick advice for you, converting `int`s to and from strings is pretty inefficient and ugly. My guess is you're just learning to program so you may want to take a little time and read about storing private variables and displaying their values when needed. That way you don't need to convert back and forth all the time

Comment: Yes, I'm new to C# primarily, have never needed to do anything like this in past projects. Thank you very much

Comment: No worries, good luck learning C#. Also if your question is answered please mark it as answered (it drives me bananas when questions are left unanswered on SO lol)

Comment: It is partially answered, im trying to implement this into the player 2's side now. Just struggling to figure out why it's not working, although will post in a second if i can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I can't figure it out for player 2, I renamed everything to a different variable or what not, and still don't really know.

Comment: https://paste.jamdoog.com/raw/uridowid - Sorry didn't post link in original answer

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
        private void SelectPos(int pic)
    {
        PictureBox[] numbers = { P1_1, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P1_10, P1_11, P1_12, P1_13, P1_14, P1_15, P1_16, P1_17, P1_18, P1_19, P1_20, P1_21, P1_22, P1_23, P1_24, P1_25, P1_26, P1_27, P1_28, P1_29, P1_30, P1_31, P1_32, P1_33, P1_34, P1_35, P1_36, P1_37, P1_38, P1_39, P1_40, P1_41, P1_42, P1_43, P1_44, P1_45, P1_46, P1_47, P1_48, P1_49 };

        //Set all picture boxes to be not visible
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i].Visible = false;
        }

        //Set the picture at the given index to visible
        numbers[pic].Visible = true;
    }

    private void SelectPos2(int pic2)
    {
        PictureBox[] numbers2 = { P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_4, P2_5, P2_6, P2_7, P2_8, P2_9, P2_10, P2_11, P2_12, P2_13, P2_14, P2_15, P2_16, P2_17, P2_18, P2_19, P2_20, P2_21, P2_22, P2_23, P2_24, P2_25, P2_26, P2_27, P2_28, P2_29, P2_30, P2_31, P2_32, P2_33, P2_34, P2_35, P2_36, P2_37, P2_38, P2_39, P2_40, P2_41, P2_42, P2_43, P2_44, P2_45, P2_46, P2_47, P2_48, P2_49 };

        //Set all picture boxes to be not visible
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers2[i].Visible = false;
        }

        //Set the picture at the given index to visible
        numbers2[pic2].Visible = true;
    }

    private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Roll();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        Roll2();
        Goes_Num.Text = (int.Parse(Goes_Num.Text) + 1).ToString();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Goes_Num.Text) % 2 == 0)
        {
            WhichPlayer.Text = "Player 2";
            P2_Number.Text = (int.Parse(P2_Number.Text) + 1).ToString();
            int p2Int = Convert.ToInt32(P2_Pos.Text);
            P2_Pos.Text = (p2Int + dice + dice2).ToString();
            int P2 = (Convert.ToInt32(P2_Pos.Text));
            SelectPos2(P2);
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(Goes_Num.Text) % 2 != 0)
        {
            WhichPlayer.Text = "Player 1";
            P1_Number.Text = (int.Parse(P1_Number.Text) + 1).ToString();
            int p1Int = Convert.ToInt32(P1_Pos.Text);
            P1_Pos.Text = (p1Int + dice + dice2).ToString();
            int P1 = (Convert.ToInt32(P1_Pos.Text));
            SelectPos(P1);
        }
    }
```